# How to design a compatibility matrix from 2 MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a MySQL database with tables for `hardware` and `software`. I would like each entry on `software` to include which entries on `hardware` it is compatible with.

```
Hardware:
| ID |
------
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |

Software:
| ID | Compatible with HW1 | Compatible with HW2 | Compatible with HW3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1                   | 0                   | 0                   |
| 2  | 1                   | 1                   | 0                   |
| 3  | 1                   | 1                   | 1                   |
| 4  | 1                   | 1                   | 1                   |
| 5  | 0                   | 1                   | 1                   |
```

Is it possible to automatically create the columns on `software` from the entries on `hardware`? And ideally add a new column to `software` when a new entry is made to `hardware`?

Comment: You're probably better of using an intermediate table that caters for many-to-many joins between the software and hardware.  The trouble with fixed columns is that you will need to add a new one every time you add new hardware - not ideal!

Comment: far from ideal @Martin *"MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table."* [Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html)  .. Pretty sure there are more then 4096 pieces of hardware out there ;-)  .. Well  InnoDB has a limit of 1017 columns per table which is even less .. Anyhow you get the idea..

Comment: @Martin thanks, I was hoping there was a way to avoid updating the software table each time new hardware was added. I' trying to understand how an intermediate table would be structured.

Comment: @RaymondNijland hopefully we'll have less than 4096 hardware revisions!

Comment: like @Martin suggested a `hardware_software` seams to be a logical idea..  But vendors most likely make a complete product line/category suitable for software (i assumming with software you mean OS like windows/linux?)  maybe take that into account in the RDMS design..

Comment: @RaymondNijland It's much more focussed than that, it is hardware and software revisions for one electronic product. I think I understand the intermediate table now, the columns would be | ID | hardware PK | software PK | Compatible |, with an entry for each hardware and software combination.

Comment: mine suggestion was based on the information which is known from the question and mine own interpretation on how i might model it.. but also including hardware changes/upgrades and software updates makes it bigger and also more complex..  How do you know for sure a OS version update didn't destroy some drivers and caused the hardware to be buggy and not to be 100% compatible anymore (i know extreme case :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Compatibility (
    software_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    hardware_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    yes_no_maybe ENUM('unknown', 'no', 'yes', 'partial' UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    notes TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(software_id, hardware_id),
    INDEX(hardware_id, software_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Insert a row for each soft/hard pair for which you have information.

After that, worry about "pivoting" to get the output with many columns.